# Running MySql on a mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I just installed MySql on a mac successfully and according to the website, I should enter the following commands in the terminal to get started:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
```

I entered the commands and on my MySQLPrefs panel it shows that the MySql server is running but nothing else happens on my terminal. It just shows

```
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86/data
```

I know this is a dumb question but what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Well, the server seems to be running, so start using it!

Comment: You can use the `mysql` command line program which is installed at `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`. There's also the excellent open source Sequel Pro GUI client available at www.sequelpro.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start MySQL command line interface:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

I think mysql on a mac atuomatically enables root access without password. If you want to change your password, check this link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/

If you want to simply write `mysql` on your shell prompt, then edit your `.bash_profile` file and add the following line at the end:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, but it is also one every person getting started asks in one way or another. If installed, how do we use it? What should be the next steps?

**First know how to verify it is running.** Your install may be set so that it loads automatically with a computer restart. While this is the most common configuration, it also can be set not to load automatically. So validating it is operating is an important first step. You can always check your server status with this command:

```
*mysqladmin -u root -p status*
```

This will return the server status and details if running. The syntax assumes that the $PATH variable has the MySQL file path added. If not, you can provide the full path to the executable.

```
*/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p status*
```

You should consider adding the folder path to the $PATH variable. The explanation for this has already been given in another answer.

You installed MySQL with the intent to build a database. It would also be worth your while to examine some of the default database structures as well. Either way, you will need to interact with the database service to create, manage, query, and examine databases and their components.

**What you'll need to know next is what to use to interact with MySQL.** For this, there are all types of options. The default and most basic is using the "mysql" command-line client in a terminal. This is found in the same path as the command above. This can be used in three ways:

1. Enter the command with just enough parameters to login to the shell and then use the shell interface to run other SQL commands: *mysql -u root -p*.
2. Enter the commands with other options that will execute your command in a single line. Use the MySql reference manual for details on this.
3. Create a .sql script with the commands you want to run call this script with mysql: *mysql db_name < script.sql > output.tab*.
   (The command above calls the exeucatable, specifies the database, inputs the script using "<" and directs the output to a file using ">").

All of this can be found in MySQL documentation under *The MySQL Command-Line Client* [(found here)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/).

It is good to know the command-line client and everybody beginning with MySQL should become familiar with its workings. However, every database person I know, myself included, use graphic tools to perform the majority of their MySQL operations. MySQL has a graphic interface as part of the MySQL workbench. This is the default tool used by many.

There are many other lightweight graphical applications that will also get you using MySQL. I only mention one by name to avoid the appearance of promoting any commercial products. Most MySQL professionals are at least familiar with phpMyAdmin. It is a web-based tool used on all OS platforms. I don't claim it to be the easiest, fastest, or best. But it works well for most needs and has been a standard MySQL tool for many years. Beyond this, your app store, your package manager, or a web search is certain to yield many options and you're sure to find one to suit your needs.

**Finally, you will need training on the commands.** There are many sources for training on the MySQL commands including MySQL documentation [found here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/). The Reference Manual will be your goto for the commands. MySQL documentation also has tutorials. There are dozens of blogs and professional video trainings you can search. How you choose to learn is a matter of personal preference (and possibly budget).

Bear in mind, that databases are seldom used by themselves. They most often store data support any number of on-premise or cloud-based applications. Taking these first steps will get you started, but you should also be prepared to understand applications that use them and how to connect them.

And of course, there's always Stackoverflow for questions. This particular question has been around for years without any further updates and it seemed that at least a discussion of how to get started was in order.